# How to find same video but with other format and resolution from very big video collection

Tags: video, editing

I have enormous video collection dating back from 2003. until today, almost 9 TB on material from varios sources with various formats and resolution. There are also some shortened version of same video (documentaries that was cut), and i think that there is a lot of duplicates.
I would ask you is there any tool that can find which videos are same or which short video clips are part of one bigger video file? 
After lot of searching I found only one tool called Video Comparer that is able to do that job, but it has limitations in number of videos processed (except pro version) and also is not free.
Is there any free tool that can do that job ( it may be for windows or linux) ???
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Paid tools exists for this because it is not an easy job. With such a large library and the extent of your use case, you will need a budget to accomplish the job.